# Uncaught reference error: function is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I wrote a function with parameters and I am trying to call that function. However, I keep getting "Uncaught reference error: "function" is not defined.

Here is my code:

```
var bColor, fColor, fStyle, bUrl;
jQuery(function changeBackground(bColor, fColor, fStyle, bUrl) {
    if (typeof (bColor) === 'undefined') bColor = '#fff';
    if (typeof (bUrl) === 'undefined') bUrl = '';
    if (typeof (fColor) === 'undefined') fColor = '#000';
    if (typeof (fStyle) === 'undefined') fStyle = 'Monda';
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ fStyle ] }
    };
    (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
            '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })();
    jQuery('body').css({ backgroundColor: bColor, backgroundUrl: bUrl, color: fColor, fontFamily: fStyle });
});
```

I get the error regardless of if I run the function from the script. Or if I run it via any of the element calls e.g. onload.

I have no idea why I am getting the error maybe another set of eyes can spot my mistake.

Comment: You didn't declare a function accessible from elsewhere. I'm guessing you're referring to your `changeBackground` "function". You are calling the `jQuery` function, and passing it a named function expression called `changeBackground`. The only place `changeBackground` is accessible here is **inside** of itself. Is this your only code?

Comment: Yes it is. Well that is embarrassing. That was not what I was trying to achieve. How do I make it globally accessible?

Comment: Don't worry, not embarrassing at all! So, just remove `jQuery(` at the beginning and the `)` at the end of it all, so it will become a function declaration. As long as this code is in the global scope, it will be declared globally. If you want to call it when the document is ready, then use `$(document).ready(function () { changeBackground(params...); });`

Comment: I did that before but I guess due to other errors it did not work. Thank you @Ian for the suggestion though. That definitely was the reason and I actually didn't realise I was creating a jQuery plugin *hidesface*

Comment: Well, you didn't create a jQuery **plugin**. Trust me, it's totally different to actually declare a plugin that can be called like `$("selector").somePlugin()`. When the `jQuery` function is called and passed a function, it's treated the same as `$(document).ready(function () { /* YOUR CODE */ });`. So technically, none of your code executes until the DOM is ready. May I ask, what exactly are you trying to accomplish and maybe I/we can help reorganize your code to work correctly!

Comment: It works when I removed the encapsulating jQuery tag. I am trying to create a function that accepts parameters to modify the properties of  sections of a page.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function to the jQuery object like `$(fn)` it's the same as `$(document).ready(fn)`. Your first parameter `bColor` is actually `jQuery`. What you probably want is to wrap everything in the ready event and use `$` inside of that closure:

```
jQuery(function($){

  // use `$` from now on instead of `jQuery`

  var bColor, fColor, fStyle, bUrl;

  function changeBackground() {
    ...
  }

});
```